# iphone binary failing to compress

Tags: iphone, binary, distribution, compression

When I try to compress my binary (to upload for app submission), I get a ridiculously small zip file (a 10 meg file turns into 300k).  I've done this a dozen times and never had a problem and am uncertain what could be causing this.  I tried restarting xcode and doing a clean build.  Has anyone seen this happen before?

Answer (score 0):

I just made a minor change to one source file, rebuilt, and it compressed fine. Reverted the change and built, and that compressed fine too. For some reason the 3 times where I built it from scratch resulted in a failed compression.